# Test if a number is a multiple of another

Tags: java, methods, boolean

i have a question in my textbook that says:

**Write a method multiple that takes two integers as its arguments and returns true if the first integer is divisible
evenly by the second one (i.e., there is no remainder after division); otherwise, the method should
return false. Incorporate this method into an application that enables the user to enter values to test the
method.**

and i wrote this code but its not working:

```
public class project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b;
        System.out.println("enter the first number");
        a = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter the first number");
        b = input.nextInt();
    }

    public static boolean multiple(int g, int c) {

        int g, c;

        if (g % c = 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The string "not working" is not a built-in error message in Java.

Comment: Your code won't even compile.

Comment: @assylias : `===` valid in javascript, not in java, I think you have a typo :)

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Haha yes obviously - my `=` key got stuck it seems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to **declare** `g` and `c` again in the function `multiple` (It is an error). Second, you didn't call the function at all, you just implemented it. And like other people answered, you need to have `==` instead of `=`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int a,b;
    System.out.println("enter the first number");
    a=input.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("enter the first number");
    b=input.nextInt();

    boolean result = multiple(a,b);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static boolean multiple (int g,int c){
    if (g%c==0){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that you can have a shorter version of `multiple` which have only one line: `return g%c==0;`

Answer (score 4):

```
//int g, c;
^^
```

Remove this line..

---

```
if (g%c==0){
        ^
```

You need to use `==` for checking equality.

---

You can actually do the below to cut down few lines as well..

```
public static boolean multiple(int g, int c) {
    return g%c == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are too many errors in your method. It actually should be like this:

```
public static boolean multiple(int g, int c) {
    return g % c == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the variables twice besides the = issue. Try this:

```
public static boolean multiple(int g, int c) {
    return g % c == 0;
}
```